# Sklearn Gaussian Regression - Memory Error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, out-of-memory, pycharm

I have those two vectors:

```
x, size 3*46208
y, size 1*46208
```

I want to fit those data to a Gaussian model using the Sklearn library (in Python). I do this like this:

```
kernel = ConstantKernel() + Matern(length_scale=1, nu=5/2) + WhiteKernel(noise_level=1)
gp = gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel)
gp.fit(X, y_norm)
```

Which gives me the following error: `MemoryError`

It works if I only take 1000 rows instead of 46208, but crashes if I take 10000.

If I do the maths, with a float taking 8 bytes, we would need (for the 10000 rows):

```
8 * 10000 * 4 = 320000 bytes = 320 Mb
```

For me it should work, but I may be mistaken. Any ideas, suggestions ?

PS: I am using the PyCharm IDE

Thanks!

Comment: if I'm not missing anything, 320Mb is for storing the x and y only. Fitting the GP takes a lot more memory - O(n^2), so in this case O(10^8). Have a look at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.08114.pdf) - e.g. in the abstract they state "However, computational constraints with standard inference procedures have limited exact GPs to problems with fewer than about ten thousand training points, necessitating approximations for larger datasets."

Answer (score 2):

10k should not be a problem, actually only limitation is memory which is available for Python interpreter on your system.

You can force Garbage Collector to free memory

```
gc.collect()
```

of increase SWAP size

Comment: Sadly, it is not helping.

Comment: try to check - 

import sys /

sys.getsizeof(gp)

Comment: it gives me: Out[172]: 80

Comment: have you tried to restart python ? do you have 64b system ?

Comment: Yes I work under 64 bit system (PyCharm is 64 bit as well). Restarting hasn't change anything